# selenium with python: program freezes when trying to open mp3 download link

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to download a list of songs using selenium with python. But after I open the download link, the program freezes if I try to open the next song link in browser( webdriver.Firefox() ) and produces following error:

```
http.client.CannotSendRequest: Request-sent
```

It works if I open a new browser for each song. How can I use the same browser again to download next song?

Comment: To use curl instead isn't an option?

Comment: @Arthur Julião I want to use my add ons from my browser so i was trying to do it with selenium. I dont know much about cURL.

Comment: If you have the link to files you want, cURL may be a better option. About your regular browser's addons, I don't know if it is possible to use them  with selenium without install all of them in selenium driver.